# Retrieve image for each search data from database using php

Tags: php, database, image

I am trying to access image for each company, when the company details is got through search. This is part of my coding.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM enquiry where product like '%$title%' ") or die("error");
$found = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($found > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo ("<img src='try5.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' height='100' width='100'><br>");
        echo ("$row[mainproduct]$row[Companyname],$row[District]<br><br>$row[description].<a href=$row[Website]>Read more...</a><br><brContact Person:$row[ContactPerson]<br>Mobile no :$row[Mobile]<br>Website:<a href=$row[Website]>$row[Website]</a><br><br><hr><br><br>");
    }
} else {
    echo "<li>No results Found<li>";
}
```

//Coding of try5.php

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT image FROM imtest";

$result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
?>
```

I am getting same image for all company details. For each company I need a different image. I have stored the images in different tables not along with data, is it right? How shall I do it using php?

Comment: may be fixed `try5.php` ?

Comment: How would `try5` know what image should be selected?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statment will always return the same result. You forgot to include WHERE, like:

```
$sql = "SELECT image FROM imtest WHERE id=" . $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: @anya And don't forget to escape that statement, to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: how to escape that statement?

Comment: in this case it could be simple typecast, like 
.. WHERE id=" . (int) $_GET['id']

Comment: @Katran i have overcome my problem .thanks for your suggestion